# Point of tangency and tangent line to a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

The following question is based on an assignment I wrote for my students to determine the point of tangency of a circle with center origin and radius r.

[image]

I have managed to get the diagram I wanted with the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\tangentpoint}{sqrt(19)}%
    \draw[-stealth] (-2,0)--(2,0) node [right]{$x$};
    \draw[-stealth] (0,-2)--(0,2) node [above]{$y$};
    \draw[thick,Cerulean] (0,0) circle (1cm);
    \draw (0,0)--(0.9,\tangentpoint/10);
    \draw[domain=0.25:1.5,smooth,variable=\x,OrangeRed,thick] plot ({\x},{(-9*\tangentpoint)*\x/19+(10*\tangentpoint)/19});
    \node[fill, inner sep=0.75pt, circle, draw] at (0,0) {};
    \node[fill, inner sep=0.75pt, circle, draw] at (0.9,\tangentpoint/10) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The output is as desired. Of course, now I am trying to develop a general form of the determination of the point of tangency and the tangent line only based on the given x-coordinate. The following does it between the intervals `(-0.99999,-0.00001)` and `(0.00001,0.99999)`. It fails at `x=0` and `x= +- 1` as seen in the code below:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand{\Xtangent}{-0.4}
    \newcommand{\Radius}{1}     
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Ytangentcalc}{sqrt(pow(\Radius,2)- pow(\Xtangent,2))}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Yintercepttangentlinecalc}{pow(\Radius,2)/\Ytangentcalc}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\mtangentlinecalc}{(\Ytangentcalc-\Yintercepttangentlinecalc)/\Xtangent}%
        %\clip (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
        \draw[-stealth] (-2,0)--(2,0) node [right]{$x$};
        \draw[-stealth] (0,-2)--(0,2) node [above]{$y$};
        \draw[thick,Cerulean] (0,0) circle (\Radius);
        \draw (0,0)--(\Xtangent,\Ytangentcalc);
        \draw[domain=-2:2,smooth,variable=\x,OrangeRed,thick] plot ({\x},{\mtangentlinecalc*\x+\Yintercepttangentlinecalc});
        \node[fill, inner sep=0.75pt, circle, draw] at (0,0) {};
        \node[fill, inner sep=0.75pt, circle, draw] at (\Xtangent,\Ytangentcalc) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The questions are: how can I address the fails and how can I decide if the point of tangency is in either of the quadrants, especially 3 and 4?

Here is a complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand{\Xtangent}{-0.4}
    \newcommand{\Radius}{1}     
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Ytangentcalc}{sqrt(pow(\Radius,2)- pow(\Xtangent,2))}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Yintercepttangentlinecalc}{pow(\Radius,2)/\Ytangentcalc}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\mtangentlinecalc}{(\Ytangentcalc-\Yintercepttangentlinecalc)/\Xtangent}%
        %\clip (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
        \draw[-stealth] (-2,0)--(2,0) node [right]{$x$};
        \draw[-stealth] (0,-2)--(0,2) node [above]{$y$};
        \draw[thick,Cerulean] (0,0) circle (\Radius);
        \draw (0,0)--(\Xtangent,\Ytangentcalc);
        \draw[domain=-2:2,smooth,variable=\x,OrangeRed,thick] plot ({\x},{\mtangentlinecalc*\x+\Yintercepttangentlinecalc});
        \node[fill, inner sep=0.75pt, circle, draw] at (0,0) {};
        \node[fill, inner sep=0.75pt, circle, draw] at (\Xtangent,\Ytangentcalc) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Just for fun hence not an exact answer. `tkz-euclide` makes this with no effort.

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide,tikz}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\myangle}{120}
\tkzInit[xmin=-2,xmax=2,xstep=1,ymin=-2,ymax=2,ystep=1]
\tkzDrawX \tkzDrawY
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){c}
\tkzDefPoint(1,1){a0}
\tkzRadius=1 cm
\tkzDrawCircle[R,thick,color=Cerulean](c,\tkzRadius)
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center c angle \myangle](a0)
\tkzGetPoint{a}
\tkzTangent[from with R = a](c,\tkzRadius)
\tkzGetPoints{e}{f}
\tkzDrawLine[add = 1 and 2,color=OrangeRed,thick](a,f)
\tkzDrawSegment(c,f)
\tkzDrawPoints[size=3,fill](f,c)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\newcommand{\myangle}{180}`

[image]

With `\newcommand{\myangle}{0}`

[image]

Comment: I had contemplated on using this but I opted for the challenge. I was also looking at the tangent construct that is referenced in the `pgfmanual` but I have not figured how to use it.

Comment: +1 without any doubt, `euclide` is the right tool to use here.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another Metapost version, that defines a function to draw the tangent.  This is just plain Metapost, so you can compile it with `mpost xxx.mp` as usual.

[image]

The arguments to the function should be a circular path, and a number between -1 and 1 for the x-coordinate.  The corresponding y-coordinate is calculated using the handy "Pythagorean subtraction" operator, documented on p.66 of *The Metafont Book* (essentially `a +-+ b` is equivalent to `sqrt(a**2-b**2)`, but more efficient).  The tangent line is rotated using the fact that `(x,y) rotated 90` is `(-y,x)`.

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

vardef mark_upper_tangent(expr circle, dx) = 
  save r, p, dy; pair p; numeric r, dy;
  if abs(dx) <= 1:
    dy = 1 +-+ dx;
    r = xpart (point 0 of circle - center circle);
    p = (dx,dy) scaled r shifted center circle;
    draw center circle -- p withcolor .67 white;
    draw (left--right) scaled r rotated angle (-dy,dx) shifted p withcolor .67 red;
    fill fullcircle scaled dotlabeldiam shifted p;
  fi
enddef;

beginfig(1);

u := 1cm;

path xx, yy, C;
xx = (left--right) scaled 2u;
yy = (down-- up  ) scaled 2u;
C = fullcircle scaled 3u;

drawarrow xx; label.rt (btex $x$ etex, point 1 of xx);
drawarrow yy; label.top(btex $y$ etex, point 1 of yy);
draw C withcolor .67 blue;
mark_upper_tangent(C, 0.4);

endfig;
end.
```

Comment: Nice catch, the use of the `+-+` operator! There was a small typo, "0.67 blue" should have been "0.67blue" (fixed).

Comment: @fpast, thanks for the comment, but `0.67 blue` works fine for me; the space between a numeric and a colour-triple is entirely optional, and I prefer it for readability and to allow Vim syntax highlighting to work.

Comment: you're right, sorry for that. I've learnt something more about MetaPost :)

Comment: This is the first time I have seen `(left--right) scaled r` being used. Interesting!

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't be sure to which direction I should automate this. Maybe you can build on it by making things more parametric.

The basic idea is to place a node on the 360 degrees arc with `pos` using also the `sloped` option. Then use that node's anchors to bypass the angle computations (all computations actually).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
place tannode/.style={insert path={
          node[pos=#1,sloped,fill, circle,inner sep=0.75pt] (tannode){}}},
place tannode/.default=0.5,
draw tannode/.style={insert path={
    ($(tannode.center)!1cm!(tannode.west)$)--($(tannode.center)!1cm!(tannode.east)$)
}}
]

\def\XR{10mm}
\draw (\XR,0) arc(0:360:\XR) [place tannode=7/8];% You can use acos for the value
\draw[red,thick,draw tannode];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting...So you are using points on an arc and then drawing a line 1 cm away on both sides right?

Comment: @azetina Yes but the name of the tangent is available later so you can draw from that node to wherever you want.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure either of the way the question must be understood. For my part, given the x coordinate I would deduce the corresponding arc point (on the upper half circle) and draw the subsequent tangent (very easily: it's the perpendicular to the radius, after all). I give it with MetaPost, since I'm not fluent in Tikz, but I can't see why Tikz should be worse at it.

```
u = 2cm; % unit length;
xmax = 1.5 ; ymax = 1.5 ; % axes parameters
beginfig(1);
  path circle; circle = fullcircle scaled 2u; draw circle withcolor blue ;
  x = 0.4 ; % any value between -1 and 1
  len = 3u; % tangent length
  t = (acos x)/45 ; % point-node of fullcircle corresponding to x
  pair I; I = point t of circle ; 
  if (x <> 0) and (abs(x) <> 1): draw origin -- I ; fi ;
  % tangent on the upper part of circle 
  pair v ; v = unitvector I rotated 90 ;   
  draw I - 0.5len*v -- I + 0.5len*v  withcolor red ; 
  draw I withpen pencircle scaled 3bp;
  drawarrow (-xmax*u, 0) -- (xmax*u, 0) ; % horizontal axis
  drawarrow (0, -ymax*u) -- (0, ymax*u) ; % vertical axis
  label.bot(btex $x$ etex, (xmax*u, 0)) ; 
endfig;
end.
```

To be compiled with the MetaFun format and numbersytem set to "double" (not compulsory, but the results are more accurate).

`mpost --mem=metafun --numbersystem="double" mygraph.mp`

x = 1:

[image]

x = 0:

[image]

x = -1:

[image]

x = 0.4:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that allows you to use style `tangent over={.5 r 2}` which put a tangent over `x=.5` to circle with radius `2` and center at `(0,0)`:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=7mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
  tangent at/.style = {
    insert path={
      let \p1=(#1) in {
        (\p1) node[scale=2]{.} -- +(\y1,-\x1) -- +(-\y1,\x1)
      }
    }
  },
  tangent over/.code args={#1 r #2}{
    \pgfmathparse{sqrt((#2)^2-(#1)^2)}
    \pgfkeysalso{tangent at={#1,\pgfmathresult}}
  },
  tangent under/.code args={#1 r #2}{
    \pgfmathparse{sqrt((#2)^2-(#1)^2)}
    \pgfkeysalso{tangent at={#1,-\pgfmathresult}}
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw circle(1) circle(2) [tangent under={.5 r 1}];
  \draw[red,tangent under={1 r 1}, tangent over={-1 r 1}];
  \draw[green,tangent over={-.5 r 2}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Notes:**

- If you want to draw tangent to circle that is not centered at `(0,0)` you can use `shift`.
- To keep it simple I haven't added parameter for the tangent length, but you can do it easily.